# Some questions about generalized symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, symmetry-breaking

The topic of generalized symmetries is rather new, as far as I understand, the first paper on them was - https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148. And I would like to grasp a deeper understanding of them. There is a chapter in the lecture notes by D.Tong http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/gt.pdf, devoted to generalized symmetry, and there are several points that I would like to clarify.

1. At first, he considers the Maxwell theory. And there are two 1-form symmetries, the electric and the magnetic one:
   $$
   J^{e} = \frac{2}{g^2} \star{F} \qquad J^{m} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} F
   $$
   The electric 1-form symmetry acts on the Wilson lines, and magnetic one form symmetry acts on the 
   't Hooft lines. The symmetry is unbroken, when the line obeys area law, and broken, when it decays by a perimeter law. As far as we know, the electric force decreases with a power law with the increase of distance, so the Wilson loop obeys perimeter law, and the symmetry is broken. The massleness of photon can be therefore interpreted as a consequence of Goldstone theorem for 1-form symmetry. 
   The question is : *why there is only one Goldstone boson for two broken symmetries? What are the counterexamples to the Goldstone theorem?*
2. Then we add an electric source, and the electric symmetry is now explicitly broken. But the magnetic symmetry may remain unbroken, and there are magnetic vortex strings. *But there should be also a phase with both symmetries broken, and when and under what conditions one may find a transitition between these two phases?*
3. As for the case of Yang-Mills theory, in the high temperature limit the gluons are free, so the similar statement should naively hold for them. But what symmetry must correspond to them in that case? All higher form symmetries are abelian, because the corresponding charge lives on codimension $2+$ manifold, and there is no notion of ordering this manifolds. Therefore, this symmetry can't be the $SU(N)$ analogue of electric(magnetic) symmetry. *Or in case of considering the system in finite temperature there is some change of logic?*

I would be grateful for any help or comment on these questions.

Comment: For point 1., I think that the responsible for the perimeter vs. area law is the $\mathbb{Z}_N$ one-form symmetry that arises in non-abelian gauge theories. It's a different one-form symmetry (in particular, it's discrete).